# iOS multiple views and MPMoviePlayer issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

I have two view controllers, one is mainController second one is movieController...

After swiping back to mainController from movieController with `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` video playing in movieController still plays as background sound.

I did release player, but no idea.

```
@synthesize viewForMovie,player;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //background image
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mits_bg.png"]];

    //gesture recognizer -to up
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                              initWithTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];

    [swipeGesture release];

    //movie player
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieDurationAvailable:)
     name:MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification
     object:nil];

    **self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init] autorelease];**
    //self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; // no control at all :)
    self.player.contentURL = [self movieURL];

    self.player.view.frame = self.viewForMovie.bounds;
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;

    [self.viewForMovie addSubview:player.view];
    [self.player play];
}

//---gesture recognizer
- (IBAction) handleSwipes:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];

    if (direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {

        CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.75;

        transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];

        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;

        transition.delegate = self;

        // Next add it to the containerView's layer. This will perform the transition based on how we change its contents.
        [self.view.superview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        **self.player = nil;**
        //[player release]; // I give it a try like this also

    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.viewForMovie = nil;
    self.player = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [thumbnailScrollView release];
    [viewForMovie release];
    [onScreenDisplayLabel release];
    [player release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: @Deepak I did edit with related code blocks. I realized something else, after swiping up to mainController from movieController if I swipe down back to movieController app crashes. I did release player in everywhere I think it might work, but have no idea why it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retaining twice when you do this,

```
self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
```

You should add an `autorelease` message to this,

```
self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I don't see a release called except for in `viewDidUnload` and `dealloc`. You should call it as soon as you remove the view from the superview. `nil`ing is a better option as your release call in `dealloc` will be on `nil` rather than a deallocated object. So after removing it from the view, make it `nil` like this,

```
self.player = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried these lines but can't make it work. I even write release line before [self.view removeFromSuperview]; but still not worked.

Comment: @tugce can you update this with your latest code so that I can see what's not working?

Comment: Can you add `[self.player stop]; [self.player.view removeFromSuperview];` before doing `self.player = nil;`. It looks like `self.viewForMovie` might be retaining the view but that should've had other repercussions.

Comment: Ok, that mutes the sound in other views; but coming back to movie view crashes the app?

Comment: You should probably move `**self.player = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init] autorelease];**
    //self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone; // no control at all :)
    self.player.contentURL = [self movieURL];

    self.player.view.frame = self.viewForMovie.bounds;
    self.player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;

    [self.viewForMovie addSubview:player.view];
    [self.player play];` to `viewWillAppear:` as you need it to appear every time you come to the view.

Comment: Could not make it work still...  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated is not getting called when I debugged. I am a starter and if the mistake is something unrelated sorry right now...

Comment: @Deepak it has been 3 days I'm struggling with this problem, now sure it is related something with movieplayer and its view. I would be pleased if you could look at the code @ http://file.erkemgroup.com:801//Deneme_TG.rar

Comment: Removing `self.player = nil;` from `handleSwipes:` should work.